# How to configure spring-micrometer tags

Tags: prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

This blog post ["Micrometer: Spring Boot 2's new application metrics collector"](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/16/micrometer-spring-boot-2-s-new-application-metrics-collector), mentions ["The importance of dimensionality"](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/16/micrometer-spring-boot-2-s-new-application-metrics-collector#the-importance-of-dimensionality).

However, it doesn't include a sufficient example of how the associated tags can be set within a Spring Boot application.

Right now, I'm using Spring Boot 2's Micrometer interface to provide Prometheus-ready output without having done any Java-based configuration.  Does setting, for example, a "host" tag require me to write some code?  What would that look like?

Here's my entire configuration:

```
management:
  metrics:
    export:
      prometheus:
        enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: info,health,metrics,prometheus
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a relevant example at [metricsCommonTags](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-metrics-getting-started), adapted below:

```
@Bean
MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags() {
    return registry -> {
        String hostname = "unknown";
        try { hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName(); }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        registry.config().commonTags("host", hostname);
    };
}
```

Comment: Also here: https://www.baeldung.com/micrometer#1-tags

Comment: And here: https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_common_tags

Comment: Similar example(s): [Stop sending Spring boot metrics to Prometheus with Micrometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73337408/stop-sending-spring-boot-metrics-to-prometheus-with-micrometer)